# Domain name or webservice not working

Tags: php, web-services, dns

I apologize for the bad formatting.
i am stuck at a point regarding the domain name or webservice.

when we call the webservice on the local server it is working but when we call the service from some remote location it is giving "404 not found error".

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more information.
Is the domain working per se? Can you access anything else on that domain besides the api?

Comment: ya when i ping at the domain it gives the response.

Comment: Is the being redirected to the correct VirtualHost internally then?

Comment: Check your Apache `httpd.conf` file, you may have configured your VirtualHost for localhost only ...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Night2, this sounds like it could only be a VirtualHost situation.

In short, if you can ping the server with a domain name from another machine then dns-wise you're fine as the name resolves correctly. Getting a 404 means you are hitting your web server - apache or whatever you're using as that's an HTTP error, it doesn't sound like a port problem. If it works locally and you're using the same name from another machine it's not a ServerAlias problem.

The syntax for setting up the VirtualHost (in apache) you can get from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

In short what that means it that you have something that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
```

The IP means that's what IP and port that VirtualHost is listening on. If you have only an internal IP there then you'll only be able to hit it interally and you'd have to use *:80 or specify IP as is applicable so apache will track with which VirtualHost to route the request to.